# Use XSLT to Generate Table with jQuery treetable Attributes

Tags: jquery, xslt, treetable

Using Saxon XSLT 2.0, could possibly use XSLT 3.0 if absolutely necessary.

The main problem is generating the `<tr>` attributes id and parent id (`data-tt-id` and `data-tt-parent-id`), which are sequences of numbers separated by dashes that the library uses to display (they must be in order). Any advice on an efficient appoach? I'm thinking of continuously updating a string variable, that is if XSLT traverses in the right order (depth-first, in order, not affected by any multithreading). Otherwise I may have to get clever with counting ancestors, etc. for each value, which seems very inefficient. I'm somewhat new to XSLT ;)

```
<table id="example-basic">
  <caption>Basic jQuery treetable Example</caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Tree column</th>
      <th>Additional data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-tt-id="1">
      <td>Node 1: Click on the icon in front of me to expand this branch.</td>
      <td>I live in the second column.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-id="1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1">
      <td>Node 1.1: Look, I am a table row <em>and</em> I am part of a tree!</td>
      <td>Interesting.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-id="1.1.1" data-tt-parent-id="1.1">
      <td>Node 1.1.1: I am part of the tree too!</td>
      <td>That's it!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-id="2">
      <td>Node 2: I am another root node, but without children</td>
      <td>Hurray!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

These examples and jQuery treetable are described in more detail at http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/#usage

I'm generating a jQuery treetable similar to their Complex Tree With Drag and Drop:

```
<table id="example-advanced">
  <caption>
    <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#example-advanced').treetable('expandAll'); return false;">Expand all</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#example-advanced').treetable('collapseAll'); return false;">Collapse all</a>
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Kind</th>
      <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
<tr data-tt-id='1'><td><span class='file'>Acknowledgements.rtf</span></td><td>File</td><td>480.95 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>CHUD</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-1' data-tt-parent-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>amber</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='2-1'><td><span class='file'>AmberTraceFormats.pdf</span></td><td>File</td><td>124.46 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-2' data-tt-parent-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>BigTop</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-2-1' data-tt-parent-id='2-2'><td><span class='file'>BigTopUserGuide.pdf</span></td><td>File</td><td>1314.71 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-3' data-tt-parent-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>Saturn</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-3-1' data-tt-parent-id='2-3'><td><span class='file'>SaturnUserGuide.pdf</span></td><td>File</td><td>694.29 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-4' data-tt-parent-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>Shark</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-4-1' data-tt-parent-id='2-4'><td><span class='file'>SharkUserGuide.pdf</span></td><td>File</td><td>12902.51 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-5' data-tt-parent-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>simg4</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-6' data-tt-parent-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>simg4_plus</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='2-7' data-tt-parent-id='2'><td><span class='folder'>simg5</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3'><td><span class='folder'>DocSets</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1' data-tt-parent-id='3'><td><span class='folder'>com.apple.ADC_Reference_Library.CoreReference.docset</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1'><td><span class='folder'>Contents</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1'><td><span class='file'>Info.plist</span></td><td>File</td><td>1.23 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1'><td><span class='folder'>Resources</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2'><td><span class='file'>docSet.dsidx</span></td><td>File</td><td>41504 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-2' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2'><td><span class='file'>docSet.skidx</span></td><td>File</td><td>43072 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2'><td><span class='folder'>Documents</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3'><td><span class='folder'>documentation</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1'><td><span class='folder'>Accessibility</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1'><td><span class='folder'>Reference</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1'><td><span class='folder'>AccessibilityCarbonRef</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1'><td><span class='folder'>CarbonAXRefRevisions</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-1-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-1'><td><span class='file'>CarbonAXRefRevisions.html</span></td><td>File</td><td>7.44 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-2' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1'><td><span class='folder'>Index</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-2-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-2'><td><span class='file'>index_of_book.html</span></td><td>File</td><td>174.1 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-3' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1'><td><span class='file'>index.html</span></td><td>File</td><td>1.1 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-4' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1'><td><span class='folder'>Reference</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-4-1' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-4'><td><span class='file'>reference.html</span></td><td>File</td><td>196.28 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1-5' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-1'><td><span class='file'>toc.html</span></td><td>File</td><td>15.92 KB</td></tr>
<tr data-tt-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1-2' data-tt-parent-id='3-1-1-2-3-1-1-1'><td><span class='folder'>AccessibilityLowlevel</span></td><td>Folder</td><td>--</td></tr>
  . . .
```

My XML source has the following structure:

```
<root xmlns="http://example.com">
    <content>
        <folder>
            <config>
                <name>Root</name>
                <updatedDate>2017-04-05T09:48:19.619-04:00</updatedDate>
            </config>
            <folder>
                <config>
                    <name>Email</name>
                    <updatedDate>2017-04-05T09:47:58.669-04:00</updatedDate>
                </config>
                <folder>
                    <config>
                        <name>Documents</name>
                        <updatedDate>2017-04-05T09:47:58.669-04:00</updatedDate>
                    </config>
                    <file>
                        <config>
                            <name>Resume.doc</name>
                            <additionalElements>...</additionalElements>
                            <updatedDate>2017-04-05T09:40:03.022-04:00</updatedDate>
                        </config>
                        <permissions>
                            <read>yes</read>
                            <write>yes</write>
                            <additionalElements>...</additionalElements>
                        </permissions>
                    </file>
                    <file>
                        <occasionalFileOrFolderResultToIgnore/>
                        <config>
                            <name>Letter.doc</name>
                            <additionalElements>...</additionalElements>
                            <updatedDate>2017-04-05T09:47:58.669-04:00</updatedDate>
                        </config>
                        <permissions>
                            <read>yes</read>
                            <write>yes</write>
                            <additionalElements>...</additionalElements>
                        </permissions>
                    </file>
                    <permissions>
                        <read>yes</read>
                        <write>yes</write>
                    </permissions>
                </folder>
                <permissions>
                   <read>yes</read>
                   <write>yes</write>
                </permissions>
            </folder>
            <permissions>
               <read>yes</read>
               <write>no</write>
            </permissions>
       </folder>
   </root>
</content>
```

Please help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having slight trouble relating your input to your output, but I think this can be done simply with `xsl:number level="multiple"`. Something like

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
  <td>
    <xsl:attribute name="data-tt-id">
      <xsl:number level="multiple" count="folder" format="1-1"/>
    </attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="data-tt-parent-id">
      <xsl:number select=".." level="multiple" count="folder" format="1-1"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
     ...
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </td>
</xsl:template>
```